# Innacurate Avg Time on Page in GA?

Tags: google-analytics

Has anyone noticed inaccuracies in GA's Avg Time on Page?

My pages all have event tracking triggers at 30 Seconds and 25,50,75,100% of scrolling through the page so I can see if users are actually reading my content.  Using user hit counts, and events I can get a pretty good idea of how much my readers are reading.

However, it's pretty common for GA to show Avg Time on Page to be 0 secs, even when 90% of the events show my users spending at least 30 seconds on the page.  Is this just being caused by bots that only read the header and don't trigger any events like scrolling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The discrepancy seems to be between Behavior:Site Content:Landing Pages and Behavior:Site Content:All Pages.

All Pages the AVG doesn't seem to be accurate.  However, Landing Pages seems to be both the most up to date, as well as accurate average time on page.